# Calling a function through a for loop

Tags: c++

Forgive my English and my ignorance (Also, I have searched a lot and could not find this question answered).

I have a program that has 5 integer variables with the creative names of "num1" through "num5".  I have a secondary function that requires two parameters, the first parameter is a number, 1-5, while the second parameter is the value of the variables num1 through num5 (If it helps you conceptualize, I am counting the number of words of specific lengths within a single user entry).

For example, if a user enters the phrase "The black cat ate a fried fish for lunch" the values would be:

```
num1 = 1 (a)
num2 = 0
num3 = 4 (the, cat, ate, for)
num4 = 1 (fish)
num5 = 3 (black, fried, lunch)
```

My code looks like this for the most part (I am only posting the applicable parts, so assume that the num1-num5 variables have been given values elsewhere):

```
int main()
{
    int num1, num2, num3, num4, num5;

    printCount(1, num1);
    printCount(2, num2);
    printCount(3, num3);
    printCount(4, num4);
    printCount(5, num5);
}

void printCount(int numberLetters, int numberWords)
{
    cout << numberLetters << "-letter words: " << numberWords << endl;
}
```

I am trying to find a way to avoid 5 lines of code calling printCount(), but I cannot find a way to have the second parameter change with a loop.  Is there a way to handle this using very simple methods?

Comment: An array... Any time you have `num1` to `num N`, you in fact need an array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very simply, you need an array. This is what your `main()` function might look like using one:

```
int num[5];

for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    printCount(i+1, num[i]);
}
```

Comment: Thank you, that is pretty much exactly what I needed.

Comment: By chance is there a way to PM someone on Stack?  I don't see any options like that.

Comment: Nope! See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/58713/how-can-i-pm-people-on-this-site).

Comment: Would you be willing to look at my code and help me find an issue?  My code is not counting the last word of the user's input.  I added some debugging cout's and it appears that the end of the line is not being counted as whitespace, although I believe I have it done correctly.  If you are willing to look at it, I am posting it on pastebin.

https://pastebin.com/Ym2WrfFt

Comment: Of course! In `isWhitespace()`, you forgot to add a case for the NULL character; you should have: `case '\0':`. Well-formed strings (like `userInput`) must end in a NULL character, so if you hit a `'\0'`, you know you've reached the last character of the string.

Comment: Do you realize that I've been beating my head against the wall with that issue since before I even started working on the other issue that I posted the question about?  I just did not know how to word it in order to ask a question.

Answer (score 2):

Use an array:

```
int nums[5];

// initialize array elements

for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    printCount(i + 1, nums[i]);
}
```

But also you need to pass words.

**And what if sentence contains words with more than 5 letters? So using fixed-size array is not the flexible way.**

I suggest you to create a function with the following prototype. Function takes [std::string](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) and returns extracted words:

```
vector<vector<string>> extractWords(const string& sentence);
```

Function would return vector of vectors. Every inner vector would contain the words with the same length. Read about [std::vector](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector).

Comment: Thanks for the information!  I don't need it to be flexible, though, but thanks for the additional information.

Comment: If English is your native language, I am ready to help you in Skype. I need speaking practice.

Answer (score 0):

Just modify main function by adding loop.

```
    int main()
        {
            int num1, num2, num3, num4, num5;
           int arr1[5] = {1,2,3,4,5};
           int arr2[5] = {num1,num2,num3,num4,num5};
           for(int i = 0 ; i <=sizeof(arr1)-1 li++){
                printCount(arr1[i], arr2[i]);
         }      

}
```